# Using .do extension as .php extension for all php files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I hide the normal PHP filename extensions and use my own extensions?

For example, using `example.do` instead of `example.php`.

I want files with the the `.do` filename extension to be treated as PHP files, so that I can access `example.do`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .do
```

This tells the server to process all files ending with `.do`   as `.php`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with nginx, or w/o using htaccess?

Comment: Thank you it worked after restarting the browser, now example.do is showing the content as php.thanks alot

Comment: Can you help me a little more how can I stop the php extensions from being accessed.?

Comment: It would be smarter not to use extensions at all and rewrite everything. That way you don't even know what the original PHP files are, and you can even protect them from direct access using some simple `deny from` rules. Anyway, with this question/answer, since you actually need to rename all your PHP files to `.do`, there's no `.php` files left, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [`sethandler`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#sethandler).

According to [the Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext), the difference is:

> If you would prefer only the last dot-separated part of the filename to be mapped to a particular piece of meta-data, then do not use the Add* directives. For example, if you wish to have the file foo.html.cgi processed as a CGI script, but not the file bar.cgi.html, then instead of using AddHandler cgi-script .cgi, use

```
<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.cgi$">
  SetHandler cgi-script
</FilesMatch></blockquote>
```